# Ubunutu (20.04 and 22.04) doesn't start up (ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug) : Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.X

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios

I had Manjaro and Windows (dual boot) on my PC and decided that I wanted to install ubuntu instead of Manjaro. However, after installation, after I do update, upgrade and install NVIDIA driver through software update app I restart the computer and get the following error (sorry for the quality - my phone doesn't take good picture from my pc screen):

[image]

One of my monitors gets stuck at the previous image, while the second one gets stuck at the following image:

[image]

This seems like a bios issue and less ubuntu but I have no idea how to solve it, so I would appreciate any help!

I have the following PC : [PC Specs (intel site)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/202783/intel-nuc-11-enthusiast-kit-nuc11phki7c.html)

Hope the info I gave was enough. Thank you!

Comment: Is secure boot turned off?

Comment: @ubfan1 yeah, I turned it off. I get the screen in the second image

Comment: This is not a BIOS issue. ACPI errors are unrelated. Probably you installed an incorrect Nvidia driver.